# How To Capture JSP output to string

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to send one email which contains lot of html code, so I'm trying to capture jsp output as string and want to send via email.

How to capture JSP output to string??

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644106/capture-jsp-output-save-to-file?rq=1

Comment: that proposed solution seems bit heavy, why i have to use file class again.. i just need output to some string

Comment: Please, add some requirements for desired solution than

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture JSP output, save to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644106/capture-jsp-output-save-to-file)